# Sprite Kit Detecting Collisions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

sorry for re-opening this title but none of the titles about this question helped me that much. In my game you are a space ship and you trying to escape from the incoming asteroids. When your ship touches an asteroid, you explode.
My codes are like these;

```
static const uint32_t asteroidCategory = 1;
static const uint32_t playerCategory = 2;
static const uint32_t laserCategory = 3;

player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory;
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0; 

asteroid.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=asteroidCategory;
asteroid.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=playerCategory;
asteroid.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=0;
```

But I don't know what should I do at 'didBeginContact' method.
please help me, thank you...

Comment: See section "Working with Collisions and Contacts"... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & astroidCategory) != 0)
{
    [self player:(SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node didCollideWithAstroid:(SKSpriteNode *) secondBody.node];
}
```

You also need to make a method for 'didCollideWithAstroid'

Comment: It doesn't enter the 'didBeginContact' method

Comment: Did you make a didCollideWithAstroid method? because that's where the main action happens.

Comment: Sure. It has a NSLog inside it but I can't get the log. @master248

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that you have to make it in this format:-(void)player:(SKSpriteNode *) player didCollideWithAstroid:(SKSpriteNode *) astroid {

Comment: If that doesn't work then try switching the playerCategory and astroidCategory in the if statement. @batiaktas

Comment: Actually my problem isn't that.The 'didBeginContact' method isn't being executed. @master248

Comment: Try one more thing. Add "(at symbol)interface ClassName() <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
(at symbol)end"
at the very beginning after your #imports. If you haven't already.